# Failed to create remoting connection

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x

Good Day!

I am doing migration from glassfish to JBoss 7.1.3 . I have .ear application which fails to create remoting connection.I guess having problem with my EJB.

Below is my EJB that deployed (From server log)

```
*10:10:56,226 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JNDI bindings for session bean named GGICache in deployment unit subdeployment "GGI-ejb.jar" of deployment "GGI.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/GGI/GGI-ejb/GGICache!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheHome
    java:app/GGI-ejb/GGICache!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheHome
    java:module/GGICache!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheHome
    java:jboss/exported/GGI/GGI-ejb/GGICache!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheHome
    java:global/GGI/GGI-ejb/GGICache!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheRemote
    java:app/GGI-ejb/GGICache!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheRemote
    java:module/GGICache!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheRemote
    java:jboss/exported/GGI/GGI-ejb/GGICache!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheRemote

10:10:56,268 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JNDI bindings for session bean named GGIDBOperation in deployment unit subdeployment "GGI-ejb.jar" of deployment "GGI.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/GGI/GGI-ejb/GGIDBOperation!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.DBOperation.GGIDBOperationHome
    java:app/GGI-ejb/GGIDBOperation!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.DBOperation.GGIDBOperationHome
    java:module/GGIDBOperation!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.DBOperation.GGIDBOperationHome
    java:jboss/exported/GGI/GGI-ejb/GGIDBOperation!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.DBOperation.GGIDBOperationHome
    java:global/GGI/GGI-ejb/GGIDBOperation!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.DBOperation.GGIDBOperationRemote
    java:app/GGI-ejb/GGIDBOperation!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.DBOperation.GGIDBOperationRemote
    java:module/GGIDBOperation!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.DBOperation.GGIDBOperationRemote
    java:jboss/exported/GGI/GGI-ejb/GGIDBOperation!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.DBOperation.GGIDBOperationRemote*
```

Below is my context lookup from my ResoureLocator.java code

```
   *Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
              jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
            jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin");
            jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "adminadmin");
            jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
            jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
      jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
    try{
    ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
    String strDSName = "java:jboss/datasources/Functional_GGI_CONNECTION_POOL";
                 ctx = new InitialContext();

                DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(strDSName);
                System.out.println("Context Look Up success>>" + ds.getClass());
                return ds;
            } catch (NamingException namingException) {

                log.error(namingException.getMessage(), namingException);
    }*
```

Below I have pasted my server.log and my application log for your reference. I am getting error like Failed to create remoting connection. I have problem in loading the intial conext with the above properties ...ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);

```
10:11:07,998 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)

10:11:08,004 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)

10:11:08,010 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

10:11:08,015 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

10:11:08,020 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

10:11:08,066 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to setup EJB remote context

10:11:08,071 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.setupEjbContext(InitialContextFactory.java:468)

10:11:08,077 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:145)

10:11:08,086 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    ... 17 more

10:11:08,089 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

10:11:08,095 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

10:11:08,100 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

10:11:08,106 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

10:11:08,112 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)

10:11:08,118 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.setupEjbContext(InitialContextFactory.java:448)

10:11:08,124 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    ... 18 more

10:11:08,128 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: EJBCLIENT000021: EJB client context selector may not be changed

10:11:08,134 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.setSelector(EJBClientContext.java:186)

10:11:08,139 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ejb.RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector.setupSelector(RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector.java:28)

10:11:08,148 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2)    ... 23 more

10:11:08,191 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/GGI]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener: ge.ifm.common.exception.GenericInterfaceException: Throwable-->Occured while loading Interface Configuration information. Exception Message is -->null
    at ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener.contextInitialized(IFMCacheListener.java:110) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ge.nbsm.weGGI.DAO.GGIDAO.getDBConnection(GGIDAO.java:62) [GGI-ejb.jar:]
    at ge.ifm.dao.GenericInterfaceDAO.initialize(GenericInterfaceDAO.java:33) [classes:]
    at ge.ifm.dao.InterfaceDao.initialize(InterfaceDao.java:239) [classes:]
    at ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener.contextInitialized(IFMCacheListener.java:75) [classes:]
    ... 8 more

10:11:08,291 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart
10:11:08,297 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/GGI] startup failed due to previous errors
10:11:08,304 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.GGILifeCycleListener).

10:11:08,318 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

10:11:08,324 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

10:11:08,331 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GGI: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GGI: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_17]

10:11:08,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 6) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "GGI.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GGI" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GGI: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GGI.ear\".\"GGI-ejb.jar\".jndiDependencyService Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GGI.ear\".\"GGI-war.war\".jboss.security.jacc Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.GGI.GGI-ejb.GGIDBOperation.env.Functional_GGI_CONNECTION_POOL Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.Functional_GGI_CONNECTION_POOL]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.GGI.GGI-ejb.GGICache.env.Functional_GGI_CONNECTION_POOL Missing[jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.Functional_GGI_CONNECTION_POOL]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GGI.ear\".\"GGI-ejb.jar\".component.GGICache.START Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]","jboss.deployment.subunit.\"GGI.ear\".\"GGI-ejb.jar\".component.GGIDBOperation.START Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]"]}
10:11:08,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011908: Unregister module: Module "deployment.GGI.ear.GGI-war.war:main" from Service Module Loader


Below is my application log 

2013-04-25 10:11:02,503 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.GGILifeCycleListener - Path for FunctionalLog4j ---- jar:file:/C:/jboss-eap-6.0/modules/com/company/test/main/test.jar!/FunctionalLog4j.xml
2013-04-25 10:11:02,512 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.GGILifeCycleListener - in log testing propertiesnull
2013-04-25 10:11:02,512 INFO  ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.GGILifeCycleListener - LOG4J Configuration [OK]..
2013-04-25 10:11:02,532 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.StartupCacher - At the Start of loadCache
2013-04-25 10:11:02,544 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.StartupCacher - At the End of loadCache 2
2013-04-25 10:11:02,552 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.StartupCacher - At the End of loadCache 3
2013-04-25 10:11:02,552 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.Delegate.CacherDelegate - getCacheValues:1
2013-04-25 10:11:02,553 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.Delegate.CacherDelegate - getGGICacheManagerRemote:1
2013-04-25 10:11:02,560 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.GGIReader - String Value from Properties file:Start of Value||End of Value
2013-04-25 10:11:02,560 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.GGIReader - Numeric Value from Properties file:Start of Value|-1|End of Value
2013-04-25 10:11:02,570 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.GGIReader - Date Value from Properties file:Start of Value|99991231|End of Value
2013-04-25 10:11:02,570 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.Delegate.CacherDelegate - GGIConstants.STR_GGICACHEHOME >>> ejb:app/GGI/GGI-ejb/GGICache!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheHome
2013-04-25 10:11:02,574 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.Delegate.CacherDelegate - getGGICacheManagerRemote:1a
2013-04-25 10:11:02,574 DEBUG ge.nbsm.weGGI.Delegate.CacherDelegate - getGGICacheManagerRemote:2
2013-04-25 10:11:07,710 INFO  ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - IFM initialize() started
2013-04-25 10:11:08,152 ERROR ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.ResourceLocator - Failed to create remoting connection
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to setup EJB remote context]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:51)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:151)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at ge.nbsm.weGGI.common.utility.ResourceLocator.lookUP(ResourceLocator.java:68)
    at ge.nbsm.weGGI.DAO.GGIDAO.getDBConnection(GGIDAO.java:56)
    at ge.ifm.dao.GenericInterfaceDAO.initialize(GenericInterfaceDAO.java:33)
    at ge.ifm.dao.InterfaceDao.initialize(InterfaceDao.java:239)
    at ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener.contextInitialized(IFMCacheListener.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to setup EJB remote context
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.setupEjbContext(InitialContextFactory.java:468)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:145)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.setupEjbContext(InitialContextFactory.java:448)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: EJBCLIENT000021: EJB client context selector may not be changed
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.setSelector(EJBClientContext.java:186)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ejb.RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector.setupSelector(RemoteNamingEjbClientContextSelector.java:28)
    ... 23 more
2013-04-25 10:11:08,191 ERROR ge.ifm.common.exception.GenericInterfaceException - GenericInterfaceException: Throwable-->Occured while loading Interface Configuration information. Exception Message is -->null
2013-04-25 10:11:08,191 DEBUG ge.ifm.dao.GenericInterfaceDAO - closeConnection method called
2013-04-25 10:11:08,191 DEBUG ge.ifm.dao.GenericInterfaceDAO - closeConnection cConn=null
2013-04-25 10:11:08,191 DEBUG ge.ifm.dao.GenericInterfaceDAO - out of if loop
2013-04-25 10:11:08,303 INFO  ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - Enterted into contextDestroyed() method
2013-04-25 10:11:08,304 DEBUG ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - contextDestroyed ()--> Context Destroyed Method Called Successfully
2013-04-25 10:11:08,304 INFO  ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - Enterted into release() method
2013-04-25 10:11:08,304 DEBUG ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - release()--> Releasing Thread Pool
2013-04-25 10:11:08,304 DEBUG ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - release()--> Closed the Thread Pool [OK]
2013-04-25 10:11:08,304 DEBUG ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - Http Client Connection Pool Releasing
2013-04-25 10:11:08,304 DEBUG ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - Closed the Http Client Connection Pool [OK]
2013-04-25 10:11:08,304 INFO  ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - Exit from release() method
2013-04-25 10:11:08,304 INFO  ge.ifm.common.utility.IFMCacheListener - Exit from contextDestroyed() method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by  removing properties to initialized context While doing datasource look up . Properties added while doing EJB Cache Remote look up. I have added anotations in my EJB session bean and EJB Remote and changed my above code due to class cast exception in JBoss javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject .

Many thanks to all..

Below is my Datasource Look up

```
try {

ctx = new InitialContext();

              String strDSName = "java:jboss/datasources/Functional_GGI_CONNECTION_POOL";
             ctx = new InitialContext();

            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(strDSName);
             return ds;

}catch (NamingException e){

}
```

Below is my EJB remote context look up

```
                Properties prop =new Properties();
                prop.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
               Context ctx = new InitialContext(prop);
                String cacheHome="ejb:GGI/GGI-ejb/GGICacheBean!ge.nbsm.weGGI.ejb.cache.GGICacheRemote";

                    ggiManager = (GGICacheRemote)ctx.lookup( cacheHome);
```

Below is my CacheBean.java(Anotations included)

```
@Stateless
@Remote(GGICacheRemote.class)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class GGICacheBean implements GGICacheRemote, SessionBean {
```

Below is my CacheRemote.java(Anotations included)

```
@Remote
public interface GGICacheRemote extends EJBObject {

public GGICacheVO getCacheValues() throws Exception, RemoteException;

}
```

I have removed my jboss-ejb3.xml and ejb-jar.xml .

My application is working fine ..